# Entity Framework 5 - "Conflicting Changes Detected"

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

In our EF 5 application, when we get a SQL Server deadlock error on an insert or update, we immediately try the operation again. However, when we attempt to do so, we're getting the following error:

```
"Conflicting changes detected. This may happen when trying to insert multiple entities with the same key."
```

This error is not coming from SQL Server. This is an EF 5 error. And we are not attempting to insert multiple entities with the same key. IOW, we're not attempting to insert a duplicate row. However, I suspect this error means something else. But I'm not entirely certain I know what the issue is. If I had to guess, I would say that on the first attempt, EF sees where trying to insert an entity. It fails because of a deadlock. When we immediately try again, EF thinks we're trying to do the very same operation again, with the same key, and doesn't like it. Not sure how to get around this.

Comment: At what rate are you getting deadlocks? 1 in 10,000? More regular?

Comment: `IOW` = "In other words". (In case I'm not the only one googling it; and if I am oh well--I don't see it used often I guess).

Comment: @qujck - Maybe 1 in 5K. It's hard to say. This is a threaded app doing a lot of inserts. I'm not sure why this would matter in relation to my question.

Comment: @RandyMinder I wondered whether you should be addressing the cause of the problem (the deadlock) instead of a symptom. Have you looked at `DbContext.Database.Connection`? It's `State` etc? I can't see anything useful in the documentation but still worth a look if you can ...

Comment: @qujck - It is impossible to fully eliminate deadlocks. You will always have them, no matter how well the DB and code is architected. Even if we have only one deadlock in 100M transactions, we want to be able to handle this one deadlock elegantly by retrying the transaction. Hence my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you might be trying to execute your queries against the same instance of the DbContext. In which case, your changes are already pending from the last try.

Since there is no “undo pending changes” on the context, you must dispose and recreate the context in between “retries”.